# How to do a Where and find by similar values

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, select, where-clause

I am working in a parking with cameras in the barriers, when these cameras saw a license plate that license will be registrated in the database as a movement.

If this license has permission to join the parking will open, but cameras are not perfect getting the licenses and maybe sometimes i will get the license with some character different.

I mean for example if the license is 7631 BHC i could get an incorrect value that could be 1931 5HD.

What i want to know is if there is any way in SQL to do a WHERE in the select to see if the license has permission, to get licenses that could be the one that camera returned.

For example, in the case I show there are 3 characters that matches with the possible value, (3,1,H).

So having these 3 coincidences of characters me in background working in C# I will say if there is more than 2 coincidences the barrier will open .

Do you know any way to this select that returns possibles licenses?

I tried function Difference() but this option does not work for me because always is returning 4 (what means the values are very similar) and is not the case, because a license with values (9999 HHH, 1234 ZZZ), by fare are not similar, except the structure of the string.

Comment: You want to do this in SQL or in C#?

Comment: @Jamiec Better in SQL but if there is a way to do this comparation in C# is not a problem.

Comment: You may want to look into Levenshtein distance.  The real answer to your question, though, is that SQL doesn't have a built-in mechanism for fuzzy matching that meets your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data and source data will always match the pattern `XXXX XXX` (8 characters, 5th being a space), then you *could* just hard-code this...

**Sample data**

```
declare @input nvarchar(8) = '1931 5HD';

declare @plates table
(
    plate nvarchar(8)
)
insert into @plates (plate) values
('1235 ZZZ'), -- 0 matches
('7631 BHC'), -- 3 matches
('1931 5HC'); -- 6 matches
```

**Solution**

```
-- version 1
select  p.plate
from @plates p
where   case when substring(p.plate, 1, 1) = substring(@input, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 2, 1) = substring(@input, 2, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 3, 1) = substring(@input, 3, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 4, 1) = substring(@input, 4, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 6, 1) = substring(@input, 6, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 7, 1) = substring(@input, 7, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 8, 1) = substring(@input, 8, 1) then 1 else 0 end > 2;
```

If you want the count of the matching characters, then you can duplicate the where clause calculation in the field list. With that you could even select only the `top 1` result when sorting descending on the number of matching characters, giving you the single most accurate plate match.

```
-- version 2
select  top 1
        p.plate,
        case when substring(p.plate, 1, 1) = substring(@input, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 2, 1) = substring(@input, 2, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 3, 1) = substring(@input, 3, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 4, 1) = substring(@input, 4, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 6, 1) = substring(@input, 6, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 7, 1) = substring(@input, 7, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 8, 1) = substring(@input, 8, 1) then 1 else 0 end as MatchCount
from @plates p
where   case when substring(p.plate, 1, 1) = substring(@input, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 2, 1) = substring(@input, 2, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 3, 1) = substring(@input, 3, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 4, 1) = substring(@input, 4, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 6, 1) = substring(@input, 6, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 7, 1) = substring(@input, 7, 1) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when substring(p.plate, 8, 1) = substring(@input, 8, 1) then 1 else 0 end > 2
order by MatchCount desc;
```

Yet another version use a common table expression (`cte`) to avoid some duplicate code. Inspired by [Jamiec's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721533/how-to-do-a-where-and-find-by-similar-values/63722822?noredirect=1#comment112682881_63722822).

```
-- version 3
with cte as
(
    select  p.plate,
            case when substring(p.plate, 1, 1) = substring(@input, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 2, 1) = substring(@input, 2, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 3, 1) = substring(@input, 3, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 4, 1) = substring(@input, 4, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 6, 1) = substring(@input, 6, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 7, 1) = substring(@input, 7, 1) then 1 else 0 end
          + case when substring(p.plate, 8, 1) = substring(@input, 8, 1) then 1 else 0 end as MatchCount
    from @plates p
)
select top 1 plate, MatchCount
from cte
where MatchCount > 2
order by MatchCount desc;
```

**Result**

```
-- version 1
plate
--------
7631 BHC
1931 5HC

-- version 2 & 3
plate    MatchCount
-------- -----------
1931 5HC 6
```

Comment: You could use a CTE so you dont have to repeat that big long expression twice.

Answer (score 0):

Given a user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountMatches(@value NVARCHAR(100), @match NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @i INT = 1;
   DECLARE @count INT = 0
   WHILE(@i < LEN(@match) AND @i<LEN(@value))
   BEGIN
      IF(SUBSTRING(@value,@i,1) = SUBSTRING(@match,@i,1))
      BEGIN
         SET @count = @count+1
      END
      SET @i = @i+1
   END
   RETURN @count
END
```

You can plug this straight into your where clause:

```
declare @camera nvarchar(100) = '19315HD'
SELECT plate
FROM Plates
WHERE dbo.CountMatches(plate,@camera) >= 3
```

or, of you want the match count in both the result and the where clause use a CTE to save calling the method twice

```
declare @camera nvarchar(100) = '19315HD'
;with data
as
(
    SELECT plate, dbo.CountMatches(plate, @camera) AS matchCount
    FROM Plates
)
select plate,matchCount
from data
where matchCount>=3
```

Live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e55ae3788616ce14c3888db19d4aa865